# GCMRegistrar.register give does not work...same code work in onother application

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have created one demo application for GCM its works perfect.But when same code i am integrating in my application gcm.register not working

this is my GCM service source code

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device registered
     **/
    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
        CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, "Your device registred with GCM");
       // Log.d("NAME", MainActivity.name);
        ServerUtilities.register(context,"","", registrationId);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device un registred
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
        CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
        ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on Receiving a new message
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");

        CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on receiving a deleted message
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
        String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
        CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on Error
     * */
    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
        CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        // log message
        Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
        CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error,
                errorId));
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }

    /**
     * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
     */
    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) 
    {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      

    }

}
```

Source code for GCM register

```
private void CheckDeviceRegistrationWithGCM()
{
    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if Internet present
    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this,
                "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }


    // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
            GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);

            // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
            // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
            GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);



            registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                    DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));

            // Get GCM registration id
            final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

            // Check if regid already presents
            if (regId.equals("")) {
                // Registration is not present, register now with GCM           
                GCMRegistrar.register(this, CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID);
            } else {
                // Device is already registered on GCM
                if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
                    // Skips registration.              
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else 
                {
                    // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
                    // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
                    // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
                      final Context context = this;
                      mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                            // Register on our server
                            // On server creates a new user
                            ServerUtilities.register(context,"","", regId);

                            Log.d(getClass().getName(),"Registration Id"+regId);
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                            mRegisterTask = null;
                        }

                    };
                    mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
                    if(!regId.equals(""))
                    {
                        ServerUtilities.register(getApplicationContext(),"","", regId);
                    }

                }
            }
```

My manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         package="com.example"
         android:versionCode="1"
         android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

        <permission
         android:name="com.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
         android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <permission
         android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
         android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

        <uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
     <uses-permission    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


<application
    android:name="MyAppName"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Themecashcity" >
    <activity
        android:name=".login.SplashActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <service android:name="com.example.notification.GCMIntentService" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.example.notification" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I tried lot but couldn't find solution please give hint so I can proceed further thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, GCMRegistrar is deprecated. You should use GoogleCloudMessaging.register method instead.

That said, your manifest has some inconsistencies :

```
    <permission
     android:name="com.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
     android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>

        <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

        <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

        <category android:name="com.example.notification" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In the first two places (the permission definition and usage), you use `com.example` as your app's package. In the third place (the category of the broadcast receiver), you use `com.example.notification`. All three places should match your app's main package name.